# convert 50 bit binary value to integer

Tags: c++, string, long-integer, type-conversion

I have a 50 bit string(in an external txt file) of 1s and 0s in c++ and need to use it in systemC(not of concern here). 
Now the problem is :
50 bits of the string need to be converted to integer first and then convert integer to string for my purpose. 
But when i convert the string to integer it doesnt reflect the result as expected.

```
 string a = "1000000001001000100000010100001001010100010000011";
 long int value;
 value = atoi(a.c_str());
 cout <<"converted value "<<value;
```

Comment: Have you read the manual page for `atoi`?

Answer (score 3):

Your friend here is `strtoll`

i.e. change

```
value = atoi(a.c_str());
```

to

```
long long int value = strtoll(a.c_str(), NULL, 2);
```

Comment: on converting the above mentioned string using the method you described i get a decimal(int) 2147483647 which is much less than the string value.

Comment: I am expecting the result after conversion as 282097789216899.

Comment: Please see edit - `long int`  is not long enough - [code](http://ideone.com/5RuxsW)

Comment: Ed, could you please share the link again, this one shows 404

Comment: got it, let me check.

Comment: Perfect, i spent time on this. The problem is systemC wont accept this but that's something i need to figure out ! Appreciate your time Ed, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11, we have [std::sto*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) functions:

```
long long value = std::stoll(a, nullptr, 2);
```